# Exporting to Excel from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, export-to-excel

I am stuck at a problem for which I cannot find any reason or solution.

I am running a SQL script to export some data to an Excel sheet. There is an application running on the other end which reads and processes the Excel sheet.

Problem: The column headers are being displayed at the bottom and the application is expecting them to be on the top row. I cannot change the functioning of the application.

This was working fine in SQL 2005, but we recently updated to SQL 2012 and this started happening.

I have not found anything over the internet to solve this issue.

This is the SQL script that I am executing

```
SELECT 
    @columnNames = COALESCE( @columnNames + ',', '') + '['+ column_name + ']',
    @columnConvert = COALESCE( @columnConvert + ',', '') + 'convert(nvarchar(4000),'
    + '['+ column_name + ']' + 
    case 
        when data_type in ('datetime', 'smalldatetime') then ',121'
        when data_type in ('numeric', 'decimal') then ',128'
        when data_type in ('float', 'real', 'money', 'smallmoney') then ',2'
        when data_type in ('datetime', 'smalldatetime') then ',120'
        else ''
    end + ') as ' + '['+ column_name + ']'
FROM tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns
WHERE table_name = '##TempExportData'

-- execute select query to insert data and column names into new temp table
SELECT @sql = 'select ' + @columnNames + ' into ##TempExportData2 from (select ' + @columnConvert + ', ''2'' as [temp##SortID] from ##TempExportData union all select ''' + replace(replace(replace(@columnNames, ',', ''', '''),'[',''),']','') + ''', ''1'') t order by [temp##SortID]'
exec (@sql)

-- build full BCP query
DECLARE @bcpCommand VARCHAR(8000)
SET @bcpCommand = 'bcp " SELECT * from ##TempExportData2" queryout'
SET @bcpCommand = @bcpCommand + ' ' + @fullFileName + ' -T -w -S' + @serverInstance

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcpCommand
```

Where `TempExportData2` holds the data that along with column headers

Comment: If you're *running a SQL script* that is causing the issue, and you don't show us that *SQL script*, how do you expect us to possibly debug it for you? We can't possibly determine the problem with code we cannot see. I find it highly unlikely that the move from SQL 2005 to 2012 caused column headers to move from the top to the bottom, regardless of what the script is doing, and I would certainly need to see the SQL script that produced that issue..

Comment: I have added the query to the question. It was working all fine a day before we updated to SQL 2012 and if I run the query again in old instance of SQL 2005 it runs fine. But in 2012 it just messes it up.

Comment: @KenWhite does this query helps now?

Comment: As an alternative and more clear way you can use `INSERT INTO` with `OPENROWSET` ;).

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the problem: You are using the `order by` in the `select into` instead of in the final `select` statement.

You should know that data inside tables is considered unorderd and Sql Server (and any other rdbms I know, actually) does not guarantee the order of rows selected if the `select` statement does not contain an `order by` clause.

Therefor, you should add the `[temp##SortID]` column to your `##TempExportData2` table and use it to sort the last `select` statement:

```
SET @bcpCommand = 'bcp " SELECT * from ##TempExportData2 ORDER BY [temp##SortID]" queryout'
```

Since you don't need that column in the output query, so you might want to specify the column names in that select statement. However, if it's not causing damage to your application that reads the excel file or to the data it produces, I would suggest keeping the `select *` to make the query more readable.